# Displaying blue with SDL2 and OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2

The title of this question is a bit misleading because I know how to display color thanks to [this](http://headerphile.com/sdl2/opengl-part-1-sdl-opengl-awesome/) tutorial. After getting it to work I decided to use it so I gutted one of my old bits of code that was a test of SDL2 when I first started using SDL2, and replaced all the renderer stuff and some other stuff, and replaced it with an OpenGL context and tried to get it to display blue, but with no luck it just displayed a black screen. Not sure what the exact issue is. [here](https://gist.github.com/TheAceShinigami/f0e525914013f39836df33d29ded1a67) is a gist

P.S. if can think of a better title I'm all ears :)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please add all the relevant code **to the question itself**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is hardcoded green in given code, not blue. Anyway, you never assign window to `window_p` pointer but use it to create context and swap. If you look at `SDL_GetError`, it will report "Invalid window".

Aside from that:

- please post code within question itself, not as an external link
- recursion in `loop` is not great at all
- you set context parameters after creating context
- function implementation in `.h` is likely to cause problems

Comment: what do you mean by "recursion in `loop` is not great at all" because it's tail recursion isn't it exactly the same as a while loop?

Comment: There is no guarantee for tail recursion optimisation in C/C++ and I don't think I've ever seen a compiler that actually optimises it out. In some other languages like scheme - it sure is.